# How to check integrity of squashfs files

Tags: squashfs

Is there a method to check integrity of squashfs files, using standard squashfs tools. At the time I'm using a separate file with sha256 hashes.

Comment: do you mean turn on filesystem checks mksquashfs -check-data ? from man page it say "enable additional file system checks" If think its checking integity after make fs.

Comment: 7-zip has read only support for squashfs. So you can use it's integrity test functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could run `unsquashfs` and check for errors - any errors should confuse the compression, like changing a few bytes in a zip/xz archive messes up at least a few blocks